# FFMPEG: Mux Elementary stream: timestamps are unset

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, multiplexing

I try to mux a h264 elementary-stream and an aac audio-stream to a mp4-file with ffmpeg.
The h264-stream was encoded with x264.

The muxed mp4 plays fine.
But ffmpeg allways throws the warning "Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0."

It's an elementary stream, so where should I get timestamps?
Am I doing something wrong, or is it just ffmpeg?

`ffmpeg -r 50.000 -i test_x264.264 -i test.aac -acodec copy -vcodec copy test_720p50_ffmpeg.mp4
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, h264, from 'test_x264.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 1200k tbn, 100 tbc
[aac @ 034eea40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, aac, from 'test.aac':
  Duration: 00:02:48.13, bitrate: 173 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 173 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'test_720p50_ffmpeg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 173 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 035ce7c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 035ce7c0] pts has no value
    Last message repeated 750 times
[mp4 @ 035ce7c0] pts has no value   7424kB time=00:00:14.98 bitrate=4059.9kbits/s speed=  30x
    Last message repeated 752 times
...
frame= 8974 fps=1477 q=-1.0 Lsize=   99764kB time=00:02:59.45 bitrate=4554.2kbits/s speed=29.5x
video:96064kB audio:3563kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.137808%`

Comment: There's nothing to do here. ffmpeg hasn't generated any TS at the demuxer stage, so the muxer is complaining.

Comment: So I can ignore this warning?
This sentence sounds, as if i would not be able to do muxing in the future:
`This is deprecated and will stop working in the future.`

Comment: That sentence has been there for a long time :)

Comment: Ok. :) I used another program for muxing in the past, till I found, that seeking those files took a really long time. Now with ffmpeg I don't have this problem, but the warning really made me worry.